# Duration of recordered file WebRTC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I implement a video streaming service with WebRTC an signaling WebSockets-Server. It is a electron-App. I want to record some video fragments and get a webm file to download. It works fine if i record a local stream (from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia), but if I try to record a remote stream, it will be a video file generated with duration < 1 sec, this trouble is only in chrome (and electron) in Firefox works it fine. If I call console.log(blob) in stopRecording () it gives somethink like this:

```
Blob(1875185) {size: 1875185, type: "video/webm"}
```

So blob size is correct and after downloading is file size is also correct, what in this case?

```
class WebRTC {

   ...........
  constructor () {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      'audio': true,
      'video': false
    }).then(
      (stream) => {
        this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig)
        this.peerConnection.addEventListener('addstream', event => this.gotRemoteMediaStream(event))
        this.peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', e => this.handleConnection(e))
        this.peerConnection.addStream(stream)
      }
    ).catch(e => console.log('error', e))
  }

  gotRemoteMediaStream (event) {
    console.log(event)
    const mediaStream = event.stream
    this.video.srcObject = mediaStream
    this.video.play()
    this.remoteStream = mediaStream
    console.log('Remote peer connection received remote stream.')
  }


  startRecording () {
    console.log('RECORD')
    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.remoteStream)
    this.recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => this.onRecordingReady(e))
    this.recorder.start(15)
  }

  onRecordingReady (e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.chunks.push(e.data)
  }

  stopRecording () {
    this.recorder.stop()
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.style = 'display: none'
    a.download = 'test.webm'

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this)
      var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: 'video/webm' })
      console.log(this.chunks)
      console.log(blob)
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      a.href = url
      a.click()
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    }, 500)
  }
}
```